# unable to change url with .htaccess in godaddy hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have to change url with .htaccess

.htaccess is stored in link folder.

My .htaccess file is

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^([1-9a-z]*)$ index.php\?u=$1 [L]
```

when i open this

'http://example.com/link/index.php?u=3ujkzf'

url it works.

But when I open

'http://example.com/link/3ujkzf' short link

I got default godaddy hosting error page.

Please Help..

Thank you for Reading..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your project is located in the `link` folder, you need to include that:

```
RewriteRule   ^link/([1-9a-z]*)$ /link/index.php?u=$1 [L]
```

By the way, you don't need to escape the question mark in the second part of the rewrite rule

Comment: my .htaccess file is in link folder still i have to change the rewrite rule to yours..  ??

Comment: @Aashu Abhee In that case you can try using `RewriteBase /link/` after `RewriteEngine On`

Answer (score 0):

try adding RewriteBase /

just below RewiteEngine On